# Chrome not opening from Android app

Tags: android, google-chrome, xamarin

The following code snippet to open Google Chrome from our Android app was working on October 2014 when we deployed our last update:

```
public void OpenInNativeBrowser(string url)
{
    Intent chromeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
    chromeIntent.SetComponent(ComponentName.UnflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
    chromeIntent.AddCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    chromeIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));

    if (chromeIntent.ResolveActivity(Forms.Context.PackageManager) != null)
        Forms.Context.StartActivity(chromeIntent);
 }
```

Now it is throwing the following exception:

> Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

How do I resolve this exception?

Answer (score 3):

t's because there's no such Activity anymore.
Try this code snippet:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Note. If your url is a local file you will need to add the uri like so; oIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "multipart/related");

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent BrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("URI"));

BrowserIntent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");

startActivity(BrowserIntent);
```